# Winforms: Enabling Localization by default (enforcing a project/solution policy)

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, localization, policy

Is there an easy way to set the `Localizable` property to true for newly created usercontrols / forms? The scope of the setting should ideally be a solution or a project.

In other words I want to say that this project/solution should be localizable, and then if I add a new form or control VS should automatically set the property to true.

**Edit:**

Although custom templates are possible, in a larger team they might not be always used. So it's more about enforcing a policy, ensuring that the team members do not ommit to set the property for the projects/solutions where it is a requirement that all forms/controls containing text resources should be localizable.

**Note:** Team Foundation Server is not an Option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is worth the effort for a property that is so easy to change and so easy to see that it has the wrong value.  But you can create your own item template.

For example: Project + Add User Control.  Set its Localizable property to True.  File + Export Template, select Item template.  Next.  Check the control you added.  Next.  Check all references, omit only the ones you'll never need.  Next.  Give it is good template name (say: "Localizable User Control").

You'll now have an item template available for future projects that has the property set.  Repeat as necessary for other item templates, like a Form.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the OP. Templates are one way of doing this, however, they are not enforcing the policy that the localization property needs to be true.

Comment: Hmya, options for policy enforcement are very limited here.  Visual Studio keeps the programmer in charge, not the boss.  You can edit the standard templates.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to write a unit test that uses reflection to determine whether a form/user control has been marked as localizable.  Specifically, if a type has been marked as localizable, there will be an embedded resource file associated with the Type and that file will contain a ">>$this.Name" value.  Here's some sample code:

```
    private void CheckLocalizability()
    {
        try
        {
            Assembly activeAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType());
            Type[] types = activeAssembly.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                if (TypeIsInheritedFrom(type, "UserControl") || TypeIsInheritedFrom(type, "Form"))
                {
                    bool localizable = false;
                    System.IO.Stream resourceStream = activeAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string.Format("{0}.resources", type.FullName));
                    if (resourceStream != null)
                    {
                        System.Resources.ResourceReader resourceReader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(resourceStream);
                        foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in resourceReader)
                        {
                            if (dictionaryEntry.Key.ToString().Equals(">>$this.Name", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                localizable = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!localizable)
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(false, string.Format("{0} is not marked localizable.", type.FullName));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, string.Format("Exception occurred: Unable to check localization settings.  {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }

    private bool TypeIsInheritedFrom(Type type, string baseType)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            if (type.Name.Equals(baseType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Please let me know if this helps.